# Cannot declare class Firebase\JWT\JWT, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

We are using Perfex CRM and trying to add Rest API module in it. When I try to create new API  and add new user its shows me the list of errors.

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: password
Filename: models/Api_model.php
Line Number: 373
File: /home/dir/public_html/domain.com/modules/api/models/Api_model.php
Line: 373
Function: _error_handler
File: /home/dir/public_html/domain.com/modules/api/controllers/Api.php
Line: 32
Function: add_user
File: /home/dir/public_html/domain.com/index.php
Line: 319
Function: require_once
```

---

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Firebase\JWT\JWT, because the name is already in use in /home/dir/public_html/domain.com/modules/api/third_party/php-jwt/JWT.php on line 22

```
Severity: Compile Error
Message: Cannot declare class Firebase\JWT\JWT, because the name is already in use
Filename: php-jwt/JWT.php
Line Number: 22
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

this issue is already fixed in new version